# jelly script - check string contains

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jelly

I am using jelly script in on of the jenkins plugin. I am newbie for jelly script. Need little help regarding script syntax.

In jelly script template I need to check whether a string var contains a particular string or not, something like this -

```
<j:if test="${someString.contains('somekeyword')}">
  <!--do something-->
</j:if>
```

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: I just looked at the template of the extended-email pluggin... the <j:if... and </j:if> seems to be correct... The tricky part is to get the correct variables from the pluggin or the system... Try printing the variables like  ${someString.contains('somekeyword')} on the webpage to make sure you are having the correct variable names...

Answer (score 3):

I use the 'indexOf' function. It returns the position of the substring, which is greater or equal zero if the variable contains the substring.
Like this:

```
<j:if test="${someString.indexOf('somekeyword') != -1}">
  <!--do something-->
</j:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should work, I'm using this to find errors in the last 100 lines of log

```
<j:forEach var="line" items="${build.getLog(100)}">
    <j:if test="${line.contains(' error ')}">
        ${line}
    </j:if> 
</j:forEach>
```